# Count Unique Values Repeated Dates

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I've got the following case I can't seem to figure out.

How to calculate the number of unique classes offered and done on specific dates.

```
| Dates | Class Number | Student Show |
| 02-06 | 1            | Y            |
| 02-06 | 1            | Y            |
| 02-06 | 5            | Y            |
| 03-06 | 10           | N            |
| 03-06 | 10           | N            |
| 03-06 | 3            | Y            |
```

Which would mean that on 02-06 there were 2 classes offered (1 and 5), both were done; and on 03-06 there were 2 offered but only 1 done.

Any help MUCH appreciated ;)

Comment: You can use `Data->Remove Duplicates` to deal with the unique aspect.  From there a Pivot Table will provide the summary by date.

Comment: This question has to do more with google drive, unfortunately there is no tag for general formula questions (at least I couldn't find it). Plus the table I need to construct must be automatic. I appreciate your answer regardless!

Comment: I removed 2 of the excel tags and put the google-spreadsheet tag in their place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you preferred to use a formula, you could use this one to find the number of classes for the current date:-

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7),IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7))>0,1))
```

and this one to find the number of classes for which students turned up:-

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((A$2:A$7=A2)*(C$2:C$7="y"),B$2:B$7),IF((A$2:A$7=A2)*(C$2:C$7="y"),B$2:B$7))>0,1))
```

See the notes [here](https://support.office.com/en-NZ/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-7889942d-824e-4469-893c-191d1efde950)

Both must be entered as array formulae using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hm, seems fine in Google Sheets if you enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter then the first formula looks like =ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7),IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7))>0,1)))

Comment: Link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oBtDLTpRtWRXDTxAUvQj5zi_UBpINLbZDGpEHCtlD-4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

Added new sheet: "Helper"
- used "unique" function based on class code
- vlookup to get class type and date
- countifs to get number of classes offered and done
- reference back from the stats sheet (where the summary table is) back to the unique list